# Error when try apply configmap to auth with EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, gitlab-ci, amazon-eks

i have the follow question. i try connect to eks cluster using a Terraform with Gitlab CI/CD , i receive the error message , but when try it in my compute , this error dont appear, someone had same error ?

```
$ terraform output authconfig > authconfig.yaml
$ cat authconfig.yaml
<<EOT
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: aws-auth
    namespace: kube-system
data:
    mapRoles: |
      - rolearn: "arn:aws:iam::503655390180:role/clusters-production-workers"
            username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
            groups:
                - system:bootstrappers
                - system:nodes
EOT
$ kubectl create -f authconfig.yaml -n kube-system
error: error parsing authconfig.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is including EOT(EndOfText) marks since it is generated as a multiline string originally.

as documentation suggests ([terrafom doc link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#generating-json-or-yaml))

> Don't use "heredoc" strings to generate JSON or YAML. Instead, use the
> jsonencode function or the yamlencode function so that Terraform can
> be responsible for guaranteeing valid JSON or YAML syntax.

use json encoding or yaml encoding before building output.

If you want to continue like this with what you have now then try to give these options with output -json or -raw

- terraform output -json authconfig > authconfig.yaml
  or
- terraform output -raw authconfig > authconfig.yaml

Comment: Thanks for help , it’s work fine !

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you the authconfig.yaml file can not be converted from YAML to JSON, suggesting it's not a valid yaml

The cat authconfig.yaml you're showing us includes some `<<EOT` and `EOT` tags. I would suggest to remove those, before running `kubectl create -f`

---

Your comment suggests you knew this already - then why didn't you ask about terraform, rather than showing us kubectl create failing? From your post, it really sounded like you copy/pasted the output of your job, without even reading it.

So, obviously, the next step is to terraform output -raw, or -json, there are several mentions in their docs, or knowledge base, a google search would point you to:

- https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-outputs-with-heredoc-syntax-leaves-eot-in-file/18584/7
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/output.html

Last: we could ask why? Why would you  `terraform output >` something, when you can have terraform write a file?

While as a general rule, whenever writing terraform stdout/stderr to files, I strongly suggest going with no-color.

Comment: OK.  this I already know, to make GitLab be able to apply the configMap, but when I run the CI / CD it appears with this EOT

Comment: The check out terraform output docs, there's a few options to try: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/output.html . starting with -raw. If it doesn't work, the -json might.

Comment: @MiltonJesus Instead of building your yaml in a string template, you can use `yamlencode()` to avoid these types of issues.

Comment: Thanks folks, this solution work’s